# Row Numbers in Excel Table

Tags: excel

I have the following basic table:

```
1|
2|    Title....
3|
4|
5|    | Row Index | Type | Etc... |
6|    | 1         | abc  | .....  |
7|    | 2         | def  | .....  |
8|    | 3         | ghi  | .....  |
9|    | 4         | jkl  | .....  |
```

Note that the table does not start on Excel row 1. Technically `ROW()-5` would work, but I do not want to hardcode the actual row the table starts on.

My formula for `Row Index` is:

```
=ROW()-CELL("row")+1
```

This works fine, except for when you edit another cell in the table. It seems that the formula assumes the row you edit is index 0 and starts the row count from there.

For instance, if I were to edit a cell in row 3 in the above table, the `Row Index` values would look like this:

```
| Row Index | Type | Etc... |
| -1        | abc  | .....  |
| 0         | def  | .....  |
| 1         | ghi  | .....  |
| 2         | jkl  | .....  |
```

After each edit, I think have to re-edit a cell in the top row to get the `Row Index` values correct again.

Is there a reliable way to display row numbers in a table?

Comment: Why do you need to use `CELL("row")`?

Comment: I guess I don't have to use it. It seemed right at the time, but does a similar job to `ROW()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is an actual Excel Table (Insert tab > Table or Home tab > Format as Table):

```
=ROW()-ROW([#Headers])
```

or

```
=ROW()-ROW(Table1)+1
```

Otherwise, you can use the absolute address:

```
=ROW()-ROW($5:$5)
```

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to get it even more universal to where it self-references the table name rather than hardcoding it, just to make the sheet more flexible to changes... but very useful

Comment: @JeopardyTempest see update. `=ROW()-ROW([#Headers])` will be changed to `=ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `CELL("row")` and just use the formula

```
=ROW() - 5
```

The [`ROW` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) returns the row number of the cell containing the formula, which is what you want.

The [`CELL` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), on the other hand, returns information about the *last changed cell*, which is why you see the strange behavior.

> #### CELL(info_type, [reference])
>
> - **Reference**   Optional. The cell that you want information about. If omitted, the information specified in the Info_type argument is returned ***for the last cell that was changed***. ...

Even if CELL returns information about the current cell, what you would get from `ROW() - CELL("Row", <current_cell>) + 1` would be the constant `1` because the two functions cancel each other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have just clarified my question to explain why using `ROW()` on its own will not produce the correct row number.

Comment: @rhughes So you subtract 5 instead of 1. See update.

Comment: Is there a way without needing to hardcode the row the table starts on?

Comment: @rhughes You could use `=ROW() - ROW($B$5)` but that is almost equivalent to hardcoding.